# Graphene-django - Mutating types with enums

Tags: python, django, graphene-python, graphene-django

So, I have the following model:

```python
class Semester(models.Model):
    course = models.ManyToManyField(Course, through='CourseSemester')

    class SemesterType(models.TextChoices):
        A = 'A', 'Winter'
        B = 'B', 'Spring'
        SUMMER = 'SU', 'Summer'

    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=200,
        choices=SemesterType.choices,
        default=SemesterType.A,
    )
    year = models.IntegerField()
```

I try to add a mutation to add a new semester. Graphene-django seems to automatically generate an Enum field for me, but how can I get it inside the arguments?

According to the github issues, something like `SemesterType._meta.fields['name']` should work, but I can't get it right, even with wrapping it inside `graphene.Argument`.

It is possible to tell Graphene not to convert it to Enum, however I'd rather avoid that if possible.

Any clue how to get that right?

Answer (score 3):

You should add
`convert_choices_to_enum = False`
to your `DjangoObjectType`

More information is in documentation in [Choices to Enum conversion section](https://docs.graphene-python.org/projects/django/en/latest/queries/#choices-to-enum-conversion)

Comment: Yes, I know. This works, but I'd rather have an option to directly access the generated enum.